# r.regression.series is not working for large number of rasters

Tags: linear-regression, grass

I have been working with in GRASS GIS for linear regression on large number of rasters. I was using

```
   r.regression.series
```

but it is only working for only 280 rasters and giving this error

```
     ERROR: Unable to open input file
          </home/…./f_format>:
       Too many open files
```

I also change the number in conf. file but its not working

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
 # <domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
your_username  hard    nofile          1500
```